# There are no child objects - ASP.net Jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

The error is caused by data section i suppose but i could not find a solution
The post fails and the error displayed at firefox firebug is

```
There are no child objects
```

Here the code

```
        var PostData = '1';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myASM.asmx/SetOff",
            data: PostData,
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

Here the web method

```
[WebMethod]
public void SetOff(string prefixText)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["SetDisplay"] = prefixText;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is in reference to your "data" parameter. It expects a key-value pair, not just a single value. Instead of "1", it should be something like { "myKey" : 1 } or myKey=1.

Comment: it works this way but this time data: '{srParam:' + PostData + '}' but it said HttpContext.Current.Session is null :D

Comment: Hm, well, I know jQuery but haven't the faintest clue about ASP, so I can't help you past the jQuery syntax I'm afraid.